# Search and replace a string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to search and replace values in a file using the values from another file. For example, `A.txt` has a string with a value `LICENSE_KEY_LOC=test_lic` and `B.txt` contains the string `LICENSE_KEY_LOC=` or some value in it. Now I need to replace the complete string in `B.txt` with the value from `A.txt`. I tried the following but for some reason it does not work.

```
$filename = "C:\temp\A.txt"

Get-Content $filename | ForEach-Object {
    $val  = $_
    $var  = $_.Split("=")[0]
    $var1 = Write-Host $var'='
    $_ -replace "$var1", "$val"
} | Set-Content C:\temp\B.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The statement "it does not work." is a little vague - can you please describe what _actually happens_ (if anything) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following, which assumes **LICENSE_KEY_LOC=string** is on a line by itself in the file and only exists once:

```
$filename = Get-Content "c:\temp\A.txt"
$replace = ($filename | Select-String -pattern "(?<=^LICENSE_KEY_LOC=).*$").matches.value
(Get-Content B.txt) -replace "(?<=^LICENSE_KEY_LOC=).*$","$replace" | Set-Content "c:\temp\B.txt"
```

For updating multiple single keys/fields in a file, you can use an array and loop through each element by updating the `$Keys` array:

```
$filename = Get-Content "c:\temp\A.txt"
$Keys = @("LICENSE_KEY_LOC","DB_UName","DB_PASSWD")
ForEach ($Key in $Keys) {

    $replace = ($filename | Select-String -pattern "(?<=^$Key=).*$").matches.value
    (Get-Content "c:\temp\B.txt") -replace "(?<=^$Key=).*$","$replace" | Set-Content "c:\temp\B.txt"

}
```

You can put this into a function as well to make it more modular:

```
Function Update-Fields {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Alias("S")]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    [string]$SourcePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Alias("D")]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    [string]$DestinationPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$Fields
  )

$filename = Get-Content $SourcePath
ForEach ($Key in $Fields) {

    $replace = ($filename | Select-String -pattern "(?<=^$Key=).*$").matches.value
    (Get-Content $DestinationPath) -replace "(?<=^$Key=).*$","$replace" | Set-Content $DestinationPath

}
}

Update-Fields -S c:\temp\a.txt -D c:\temp\b.txt -Fields "LICENSE_KEY_LOC","DB_UName","DB_PASSWD"
```

**Explanation - Variables and Regex:**

- `$replace` contains the result of a string selection that matches a regex pattern. This is a case-insensitive match, but you can make it case-sensitive using `-CaseSensitive` parameter in the `Select-String` command.
- `(?<=^LICENSE_KEY_LOC=)`: Performs a positive lookbehind regex (non-capturing) of the string `LICENSE_KEY_LOC=` at the beginning of a line.

  - `(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind mechanism of regex
  - `^` marks the beginning of the string on each line
  - `LICENSE_KEY_LOC=` is a string literal of the text
- `.*$`: Matches all characters except newline and carriage return until the end of the string on each line

  - `.*` matches zero or more characters except newline and carriage return because we did not specify single line mode.
  - `$` marks the end of the string on each line
- `-replace "(?<=^LICENSE_KEY_LOC=).*$","$replace"` is the replace operator that does a regex match (first set of double quotes) and replaces the contents of that match with other strings or part of the regex capture (second set of double quotes).

  - `"$replace"` becomes the value of the `$replace` variable since we used double quotes. If we had used single quotes around the variable, then the replacement string would be literally `$replace`.
- `Get-Content "c:\temp\A.txt"` gets the contents of the file A.txt. It reads each line as a `[string]` and stores each line in an `[array]` object.

**Explanation - Function:**

- Parameters

  - `$SourcePath` represents the path to the source file that you want to read. I added alias `S` so that `-S` switch could be used when running the command. It validates that the path exists (`{Test-Path $_}`) before executing any changes to the files.
  - `$DestinationPath` represents the path to the source file that you want to read. I added alias `D` so that `-D` switch could be used when running the command. It validates that the path exists (`{Test-Path $_}`) before executing any changes to the files.
  - `$Fields` is a string array. You can input a single string or multiple strings in an array format (`@("string1","string2")` or `"string1","string2"`). You can create a variable that contains the string array and then just use the variable as the parameter value like `-Fields $MyArray`.

Comment: Thank you, it works great. I am wondering how to parameterize this since I have a list of different values that need to be searched and replaced on B.txt file. For example, A.txt fontains the following values. LICENSE_KEY_LOC=test_lic
DB_UNAME=test_DB
DB_PASSWD=sdfssdfsf
SQLSERVER_SCHEMA_NAME=dfhosdfhsdof

Comment: @signalhouse I added another code block that will allow you to add more fields to replace. Just update the `$key` array items. We could make this a function where you pass in parameters including the file names as well.

Comment: I am a newbie to PS. Can you please explain how your code works so that it will be a good learning for me. Thank you.

Comment: @signalhouse I added some explanation. Let me know if that is sufficient.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and answering my questions. This is really helpful.